# Java / Kotlin generics

Tags: java, android, templates, generics, kotlin

i am having a template / generics question.

This is the code i have at the moment

```
data class RealmWatcher<T>(
        val results: RealmResults<T>,
        val handler: (RealmResults<T>) -> Unit)
```

And and using this in an Android fragment to listen to specific results and execute actions based on the changes. So lets take this as an example

```
private val realmListener = arrayOf(
            RealmWatcher<Notification>(Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Notification::class.java).equalTo("isNew", true).findAll(),
                                       { n: RealmResults<Notification> ->
                                           // DO STUFF
                                       })
```

I am doing this while start / stop of the fragment

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    // start listening and execute
    realmListener.forEach { it.handler(it.results) }
    realmListener.forEach { it.results.addChangeListener(it.handler) }
}

override fun onPause() {
    // stop listening
    realmListener.forEach { it.results.removeChangeListener(it.handler) }
    super.onPause()
}
```

It works only when i am using one type (like `Notification` above). How should I define that if i want to use different types in the form of

```
private val realmListener = arrayOf(
            RealmWatcher<Notification>(Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Notification::class.java).equalTo("isNew", true).findAll(),
                                       { n: RealmResults<Notification> ->
                                       // TODO STUFF
                                       }),
            RealmWatcher<Project>(Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Project::class.java).equalTo("isOdd", true).findAll(),
                                       { n: RealmResults<Project> ->
                                         // TODO STUFF
                                       })
                                       )
```

When mixing the types (`Notification` and `Project`) I will get a `Type mismatch` error.

And when defining the

```
private val realmListener:Array<RealmWatcher<out Any>>
```

I will also get `Type mismatch` errors

**How can I define the Array to have several different RealmWatcher with different types T?**

Comment: Hm, can you post the actual errors and where they occur?

Comment: Put variance on your realm watcher class i.e. `data class RealmWatcher<out T>`

Comment: @SimY4 That won't work, as `T` is also used in `in` position in the code. See my answer for a working solution that also encapsulates the logic better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing exactly what you want is going to be tricky, because I don't know of a way to tell the compiler that what you're doing is actually safe. Adding variance, like one of the comments suggests, won't work as `T` is used in both `in` and `out` positions.

However, you could take a different approach. Extend your `RealmWatcher` like this:

```
data class RealmWatcher<T>(
    val results: RealmResults<T>,
    val handler: (RealmResults<T>) -> Unit
) {
    fun attach() {
        handler(results)
        results.addChangeListener(handler)
    }
    fun detach() {
        results.removeChangeListener(handler)
    }
}
```

and then use those two additional functions in your lifecycle callbacks:

```
fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    // start listening and execute
    realmListener.forEach { it.attach() }
}

fun onPause() {
    // stop listening
    realmListener.forEach { it.detach() }
    super.onPause()
}
```

This will do what you need it to do without creating a problem because of the mixed generic parameters.